# 録音音声のフォーマット設定時のエラー

Tags: ios, swift

音声のフォーマットを設定する際、以下のプログラムでエラーが生じてしまいます。

追記：UIntを加えたのですが、`soundRecorder` の `as [NSObject : AnyObject]` の部分でエラーが出てしまいます。

```
let recordSettings: [String : Any] = [AVFormatIDKey:UInt(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 160000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 8000.0 ]

var error : NSError?

soundRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: &error)//ここでエラーが出ます。
```

お気づきの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご指導のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

編集前の質問のコードは、Xcode6では大丈夫だったのですが、Xcode7/iOS9 SDKになって、
`kAudioFormatAppleLossless` が `Int` から `UInt32` になり、`UInt32` などのビット数指定の数値型は、`NSNumber`に自動変換されないため、エラーになります。

なので、Xcode7では明示的に `UInt` 等の `AnyObject`互換の型に変換してあげる必要があります。

それとそのままだと `recordSettings` が `NSDictionary` になってしまうので `AVAudioRecorder` のイニシャライザが要求する `[String:AnyObject]` を明示的に指定します。

```
let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
    AVFormatIDKey : UInt(kAudioFormatAppleLossless), // <-- これ
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 160000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 8000.0
]
```

`NSNumber(unsingedInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless)` でもいいのですが、
`UInt` のほうが文字数が少ないので。

あと、 `AVAudioRecorder` イニシャライザは `throw` するようになったので、`try` などしてエラーをハンドルするなり、無視するなりする必要があります。[`Swift` の `throw` エラーハンドリング](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508)については、質問の趣旨と違うので、ここでは説明しません。

Answer (score 1):

コンパイラが型を推論できていないので、例えば型を指定します。`var recordSettings: [String: Any]`の部分です。

```
var recordSettings: [String: Any] = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 160000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 8000.0 ]
```

Comment: 型を指定したところ、エラーがなくなりました。
ご丁寧に有りがとうございました。